# Is there a correlation between windows versions and driver version numbers, and could that help in identifying old drivers?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, drivers

what is the meaning behind the numbering of driver version numbers - I see a correlation e.g. many starting with the number 10?

for example running this command to list drivers `Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select DeviceName, Manufacturer, DriverVersion`

[image]

Here is the same  command on a windows 7 system

[image]

I see microsoft using driver version numbers there beginning with 6, but probably not just microsoft. And virtual clonedrive is close with a version number starting with 5.

There are some anomalies in numbering like HP uses 20 and 40 there.

Is there any correlation between driver number and the windows version it is built for, and would that give any indication of whether a driver is old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a relation.

Usually the Version number syntax follows the following method `Major.Minor.Build.Revision`.

The OS version strings are same as Driver version, as found in `ver` command in Cmd. These all could be found at https://ss64.com/nt/ver.html

Comment: This only applies to drivers supplied by Microsoft

Comment: Yes @Mokubai then you have to see the versioning scheme of third-party drivers, such as HP